# python gearman worker on ec2 instance not responding

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gearman

I have two aws ec2 instances. Client is running on first ec2 instance and worker is running on second ec2 instance. But worker on second ec2 instance is not responding to clients job and not even throwing any error.

client.py:

```
import python3_gearman as gearman
def check_request_status(job_request):
    if job_request.complete:
    print("Job %s finished!  Result: %s - %s" % (job_request.job.unique, job_request.state, job_request.result))
    elif job_request.timed_out:
    print("Job %s timed out!" % job_request.unique)
    elif job_request.state == JOB_UNKNOWN:
    print("Job %s connection failed!" % job_request.unique)

gm_client = gearman.GearmanClient(['34.253.103.1:4730'])  # 34.253.103.1 :- ip address of worker

completed_job_request = gm_client.submit_job("reverse", "Hello World!")
check_request_status(completed_job_request)
```

worker.py:

```
import python3_gearman as gearman
gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['46.51.130.13:4730'])  # 46.51.130.13 :- ip address of client

def task_listener_reverse(gearman_worker, gearman_job):
    print('Reversing string: ' + gearman_job.data)
    return gearman_job.data[::-1]

# gm_worker.set_client_id is optional
gm_worker.set_client_id('python-worker')
gm_worker.register_task('reverse', task_listener_reverse)

# Enter our work loop and call gm_worker.after_poll() after each time we timeout/see socket activity
gm_worker.work()
```

Ran gearmand using below command on both the instance:

```
sudo gearmand --listen=0.0.0.0 -d
```

Please suggest what's wrong on above method/code.

Comment: could you connect from pythons environment to `gearmand` at all? Test it with `nc -v 46.51.130.13 4730`. It could be helpful for you to take a look in `gearmand` logs.

Comment: You should only have one instance of Gearman server running.  Both client and worker need connect to Gearman server IP.  It looks like you are connecting to different instances of gearmand - you have different IPs configured.